# spark hive and datanucleus

Tags: java, maven, hive, apache-spark

In a java spark (&spring) project, I used SparkHiveContext and got an initial error `ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory` when doing:

```
// sparkHiveContext = new JavaHiveContext(sparkContext);
// JavaRDD<MyClass> myRdd = ...
JavaSchemaRDD schema = sparkHiveContext.applySchema(myRdd, MyClass.class);
schema.registerTempTable("temptable");
sparkHiveContext.sql("CREATE TABLE mytable AS SELECT * FROM temptable");
```

So I added ̀`datanucleus-core` `datanucleus-api-jdo` and `datanucleus-rdbms` maven dependencies, version 3.2.1.

But now I get the error `...NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.FlushOrdered`.

The really strange thing is that I do find this class in the datanucleus-core-3.2.1.jar in the generated war WEB-INF/lib. And in no other jar of the war.

Does anyone have an idea how this could happen?

Details:

- maven project
- spark 1.1.1 (with *provided* scope)
- include $SPARK_HOME/lib/spark-assembly-1.1.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar to the servlet container
- use maven jetty plugin to run (i.e. as servlet container)
- it worked well before using spark-hive
- I don't have hive installed, but we told me it wasn't necessary
- I use spark hive to manage the sql interface to some hdfs files, mainly because spark sql (1.1.1) is not good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this was really stupid: I used version 3.2.1 for all datanucleus dependencies while the datanucleus-core provided by spark was actually 3.2.2 :-\

Anyway, on my way I made [this very simple prototype of spring webapp using spark-hive](https://github.com/julien-diener/sparkhivewebapp). If anyone is interested.